# Determine current environment variables

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables

App: C#, .NET4, Windows 7

When an app starts up, it gets a copy of the current environment variables and they stay constant for the life of that app.  I want to know how to get the actual current environment variables, allowing me to react to changes.

Do I need to go to the registry?  I've pondered spawning a cmd.exe and dumping the output of set, but I'd prefer something less hacky.

Thanks

Comment: I think spawning cmd would not work: "By default, a child process inherits the environment variables of its parent process."

Comment: Thanks, I kinda thought so, Martinho.  That's the big reason I didn't try that experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following overload might give you what you want:

```
String Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(String, EnvironmentVariableTarget)
```

Try passing `EnvironmentVariableTarget.User` or `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine`.

To get all of the variables, call

```
IDictionary Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget)
```

Comment: I've verified this does work for User variables, didn't test machine but from the docs I'd expect it would.  Unfortunately, I also verified that the environment var I was looking for (CLIENTNAME) is only a Process variable.  So much for an easy way to see who's remoted in to win7.

Comment: If the questions is, "How can find out who is remoted in to Windows 7?", then I would suggest looking into WMI http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384642(v=VS.85).aspx.